# Remove overlapping time-periods

Tags: sas

is there a way to remove time periods (for the same variable, in my case "absence_reason") when they are sub-periods of larger ones?

Suppose to have the following:

> ```
> data DB1;
> input ID :$20. (Start End)(:date9.) Absence_reason :$20.;
> format Start End date9.;
> cards;
> 0001 01JAN2015 06FEB2015 vacation 
> 0001 02JAN2015 02JAN2015 vacation 
> 0001 13APR2015 31DEC2015 sick leave 
> 0002 01JAN2017 12JUL2017 vacation 
> 0002 12JUN2017 18JUN2017 vacation 
> ...;
> ```

Desired output:

> ```
> data DB1;
> input ID :$20. (Start End)(:date9.) Absence_reason :$20.;
> format Start End date9.;
> cards;
> 0001 01JAN2015 06FEB2015 vacation 
> 0001 13APR2015 31DEC2015 sick leave 
> 0002 01JAN2017 12JUL2017 vacation 
> ...;
> ```

Sub-periods are always completely overlapping (considering Start and End).

Thank you in advance

Comment: What do you want to happen with partially overlapping periods, like `01JAN2018 12MAY2018` and `01MAR2018 12JUL2018`?

Comment: I have not 2018 in my example, or is there something wrong with the post?

Comment: The question is, what if two periods overlap, but the one is not part of the other. _(I deliberatly selected another year, because it is another example)_

Comment: ok, no, there are not that cases.

Comment: It is bad programming practice to trust that

Comment: What do you want to happen when you have 2 events one after another: 0002 01JAN2017 12JUL2017 vacation      0002 13JUL2017 18JUL2017 vacation? So, if someone prolonged their vacation. And what those sub-periods even are? Don't they have a special tag in a database to remove them if you don't need them?

Comment: So: they are errors from administrative database. In other words the person that signs the absence of workers made a mistake while reporting two times something already reported. I have no flags/tags in original data. Events one after another but that do not overlap will stay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I agree with Dirk that  it is a not very reliable practice this code might help you to get the idea:

```
proc sort data=DB1;
  by Id Absence_reason Start;
run;

data will;
  set DB1;
  by Id Absence_reason Start;

  lastEnd = lag(End);
  if First.Absence_reason then 
    output; 
  else do;
    if lastEnd < Start then 
      output;
  end;
  drop lastEnd ;
run;
```

Output:

```
0001    13APR2015   31DEC2015   sick
0001    01JAN2015   06FEB2015   vacation
0002    01JAN2017   12JUL2017   vacation
```